# Requests with Aurelia Framework

Tags: javascript, aurelia

There is a file (main.js maybe) where I can set the baseUrl for all my requests?

I’m starting in Aurelia, so sorry if is a stupid question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change my API BaseUrl in Aurelia for development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030700/how-can-i-change-my-api-baseurl-in-aurelia-for-development)

Comment: Are you wanting to set the baseURL for requests made by an HTTP Client or the baseURL for used when requestings assets (HTML/JS/CSS) for your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [withBaseUrl configuration option](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/api/aurelia/fetch-client/latest/class/HttpClientConfiguration) on the HttpClient.

Here's an example from http://www.elanderson.net/2015/09/aurelia-with-asp-net-5-and-web-api/ in the App class.

```
import {HttpClient} from 'jspm_packages/github/aurelia/fetch-client@0.1.2/aurelia-fetch-client.js';
import 'fetch';

@inject(HttpClient)
export class App{ 
    constructor(http){
        http.configure(config => {
            config
              .useStandardConfiguration()
              .withBaseUrl('http://localhost:14830/api/');
        });

        this.http = http;
    }
}
```